# Show that $(c_{0})'$ and $(c)'$ are isometrically isomorphic.

Tags: functional-analysis, isometry, vector-space-isomorphism, dual-spaces

We consider $c_{0}$ the set of all complex convergent sequences to $0$, and $c$ the set of all complex convergent sequences.  Show that $(c_{0})'$ and $(c)'$ are isometrically isomorphic. (where $'$ means dual)

**Remark:** My idea consists of the following:

We know that $c_{0}\subset c$, then we consider the map 
$$\begin{array}{rcl}\Gamma:(c)'&\rightarrow&(c_{0})'\\ g&\mapsto & \left.g\right|_{c_{0}} \end{array}$$
where $|_{c_{0}}$ means restrction to $c_{0}$. I managed to show that $\Gamma$ is a linear continuous bijection with $\left\|\Gamma(g)\right\|\leq \left\|g\right\|$.

**The problem:** I have not been able to show the other inequality, that is,$\left\|\Gamma(g)\right\|\geq \left\|g\right\|$.

Comment: The inequality you want to prove is false - consider the functional taking a sequence to its limit.

Comment: You probably know the isometric isomorphism $(c_0)' \to \ell^1(\mathbb{N})$. So try to find an isometric isomorphism $\ell^1(\mathbb{N}) \to (c)'$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The dual of $c$ is isometrically isomorphic to $\ell^1$. This is already written in a bunch of places, so I won't repeat the proof:

- [Isometric isomorphism from $\ell^1$ to $c^*$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1580466/isometric-isomorphism-from-ell1-to-c)
- [Isometrical isomorphism $T : \ell _1\to c^*$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1942370/isometrical-isomorphism-t-ell-1-to-c?rq=1)
- [$c^*$ isometrically isomorphic to $\ell_1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1938883/c-isometrically-isomorphic-to-ell-1)
- [The dual space of $c$ is $\ell^1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/678911/the-dual-space-of-c-is-ell1)

It is also true (and easier to show) that the dual of $c_0$ is isometrically isomorphic to $\ell^1$:

- [Isometric identification of $c_0^*$ and $ \ell^1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/517227/isometric-identification-of-c-0-and-ell1)
- [linear operator from $\ell^1$ to $(c_0)'$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2308372/linear-operator-from-ell1-to-c-0)
- [Show a map from $(c_0)^*$ to $\ell^1$ is an isometry](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1224494/show-a-map-from-c-0-to-ell1-is-an-isometry)